# Android Studio Emulator 7.1.1 crashes often

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Could anybody suggest me the solution to solve the crash with Android studio Emulator 7.1.1?? . Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
Custom VM options:
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: Even the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182131/snapshot-and-use-host-gpu-options-missing-from-avd-settings to disable the host GPU as per the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912055/android-emulator-crash-linux-with-error/27832292#27832292 din't solve the emulator crash issue..

Comment: That's the crash I've been hunting down for quite a while! Could you please post the whole assertion failure message, with the emulator version here? Or, even better, I'd appreciate you creating a bug on b.android.com for the emulator. I'd like to help a lot!

Comment: api 24 emulator crashing